# Why Do These Divs Overlap?

Tags: html, css

This makes no sense to me. I've been trying to research this, but I have no idea why it's overlapping. I have a feeling that it is because I used the 'img' tag or because I need to use some kind of position type somewhere, but I have tried them and it didn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/FhU3r/

```
#picdiv {
height:405px;
width:320px;
border:1px solid black;
margin:15px;
    float:left;
 }

#rightdiv {
width:620px;
height:320px;
border:1px solid black;

 } ​

<div id="picdiv">
<center><img src="img.png" /></center>
<div id="quote">
"Here's Some Inspirational Text Like OMG!"
</div> <!-- end quote -->
</div> <!-- end pic container -->

<div id="rightdiv">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>​
```

**I updated it, but still can't get it to work** : http://jsfiddle.net/FhU3r/15/

Comment: regarding your edit, it works fine for me but the second box is very wide. when I changed the width to something that fits on my screen it worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/FhU3r/20/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I'd add `float: left` to `#rightdiv`.

This will make the paragraph appear just to the side of the image and caption.  Of course, it will wrap to the next line if you don't have enough width in the parent container so that's something to look out for.

Comment: interesting, that worked. but how do you make it stay where it is no matter what the browser size is? i just tried to do it in jfiddle, but it keeps bumping it below the other div if the resolution is too small. i added position:fixed but it didnt work: see here: http://jsfiddle.net/FhU3r/11/ try changing the width of the bottom box and you will see it keeps going below then going to the side when theres enough space

Comment: updated it again with a container div with your suggestion that was big enough, but stll didn't work: take a look : http://jsfiddle.net/FhU3r/15/

Comment: @sab - The container wasn't quite wide enough (by 4 pixels).  You have to add up the width, margins, and borders.  It looks like you didn't count the borders.  This works... http://jsfiddle.net/FhU3r/23/  (I made #picdiv 4 pixels narrower)

Comment: smart man.. smart smart man. i forgot about those damn margins and borders lol

Comment: @sab - Glad to help.  And if you wanted a liquid layout that scales to the browser size, then check this out... http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins/

Answer (score 3):

First of all, note that your *borders* overlap, but the content does not.

The float property really has two conceptually distinct uses that I know of, even if the technical implementation is identical. The first is getting content to flow around an element, and the second is for putting elements next to each other in a layout. From what I can see, you're looking for the second but implementing the first.

Lets go over the first, making content flow around an element.

Say you are publishing an article. You have many paragraphs of text, plus some images to insert throughout the body. They should "float" on one side, left or right, and the paragraph text should flow around them. And, *the box that contains the paragraph text flowing around the image should also contain the image itself*. That's what you are seeing in your code.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FhU3r/14/)

And then there's the second, where you want to stick things next to each other for layout purposes. That seems to be what you're after.

Well, the accommodation of the first purpose sort of makes using floats for the second purpose a bit ugly. I don't know the history, but if I had to guess, I'd say the float specs were designed around the first purpose.

Basically you just need to float *both* elements left, with `float: left;`. The one on the right will then not try to flow around the one on the left, but rather exist in its own vertical column. Even if it's longer than the one on the left, it will just extend its column instead of flowing underneath the one on the left.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FhU3r/16/)

One of the ugly aspects of this approach is that you can't just carelessly put something underneath the two columns. If you just throw in another paragraph, it will wrap around *both* floated elements:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FhU3r/18/)

So to fix that, you need to add `clear: left` to whatever you want to be beneath the two left-floated elements.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FhU3r/19/)

For the definitive source on this, check out the [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats).

[This article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/) also does a pretty great job addressing common issues with floats.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have one floated div and another unfloated div, the floated div is taken out of the normal flow of the document. You can fix this by adding `float:right;` to the `#rightdiv`.

If you want one to show up on the left and the other on the right - which, from the ids of your divs, it sounds like you do :) - then you need to manually set the width of them (px, %, em - whatever you need) so that combined they will fit horizontally within the containing element. If the two floated elements can't fit on the same line, the second element gets "bumped" to the second line.

Also, if you have more content that goes below these divs, you will probably want to "clear" the floated elements with something like this:

```
<br style="clear:both" />
```

That will ensure that any elements below will not overlap with the floated elements. I hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting choice of `<br style="clear:both" />` over `<span style="clear:both"></span>`, something I've seen more often. On the surface I like the semantics, but does it add some space below as well?

Comment: i see. so i need a container over the both of them. let me try that

Comment: i dont understand. i tried to make with a containing div, but it still didn't work. i dnt get why this isnt working right now because ive done stuff like this in the past and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/FhU3r/15/

Answer (score 0):

Floating a div takes it out of the "flow". So you have kinda "floated" the div ontop of the image. If you float the image it should position how you want.

Comment: in what way should i float the img? i floated it left, but then the image disappeared for some reason